# Python: Use JSON list as parameters in SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, json

```
res_vod = db.execute(""" 
SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000.0) AS decimal(6,1))
FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p 
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId 
INNER JOIN Calendar c 
ON r.DayId = c.DayId
WHERE c.WeekCodeInYear BETWEEN 30 AND 50
AND p.VODEST IN ('VOD')
AND p.Distributor IN ({})
GROUP BY c.WeekCodeInYear 
ORDER BY c.WeekCodeInYear""".format(', '.join(["'" + studio + "'" for studio in _studios]))  )
```

The above code allows me to add a list as a parameter for the query. However my requirement is to add multiple parameters.
In the above code `_studios` is the list that contains the parameters.

`_studios = ["WARNER","TF1","GAUMONT","PATHE","STUDIOCANAL","FRANCETV","M6SND"]`

I have another list like:
`_vodest = ["VOD","EST"]`
I want to add this as a parameter for `p.VODEST` in the query.

I could have easily done this by using a `%` but it has to be noted that the list contains double quotes`("WARNER")` but the SQL query requires single quote`('WARNER')`

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Always use parametrized sql](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) when possible:

```
def placemarks(n):
    return ','.join(['%s']*n)

sql = """SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000.0) AS decimal(6,1))
         FROM RawData r
         INNER JOIN Product p 
         ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId 
         INNER JOIN Calendar c 
         ON r.DayId = c.DayId
         WHERE c.WeekCodeInYear BETWEEN 30 AND 50
         AND p.VODEST IN ({})
         AND p.Distributor IN ({})
         GROUP BY c.WeekCodeInYear 
         ORDER BY c.WeekCodeInYear""".format(
             placemarks(len(_vodest)), 
             placemarks(len(_studios)))
args = [_vodest + _studios]
res_vod = db.execute(sql, args)
```

Comment: This is a much more cleaner and an efficient way. Thank you :)